# Dynamic_cast failing

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast

Suppose the code is as such:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class dog
{
 public:
   virtual ~dog()
   {

   }
};

class yellowdog : public dog
{
  int age;
  public:
    void bark() { cout << "woof." << endl;}
};

int main()
{
  dog *pd = new dog();
  yellowdog *py = dynamic_cast<yellowdog*>(pd);
  py->bark();
  cout << "py = " << py << endl;
  cout << "pd = " << pd << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
woof.
py = 0x0
pd = 0x7fd4d34000e0
```

I understand why py = 0. I know that there is a run-time check and in that run-time check, there is a failure to convert `dog` to `yellowdog`, hence the value of py = 0.

My question is why `py->bark()` still can work. Why is that it is still able to print out "woof."?

My apologies to the code before. Do check now..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`py` is a null pointer, so `py->bark()` invokes undefined behavior. Anything can happen, including things appearing to work. Unlike Java or C#, C++ has no guarantee of failing immediately if you access a null pointer. In the name of efficiency, C++ compilers will generally elide null pointer checks.

As it happens, `bark()` does not use `this` at all, so it is not surprising that it would work okay. You should not rely on it—there is no guarantee that it will work—but it's not surprising.

Comment: how to avoid such undefined behavior?

Comment: @lakesh _"how to avoid such undefined behavior?"_ Don't dereference `nullptr` :P ...

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons the casting fails:

1. You're casting a pointer to a non-pointer type, and then assigning this to a pointer. This should give you compiler errors.
2. `pd` is a pointer to `dog` and not a `yellowdog`, so no downcast is possible, and `py` would be a null pointer (and dereferencing this leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

It the *undefined behavior* from the second point that is giving you trouble. Undefined behavior is, by its very definition, undefined, and anything can happen. From crashes, to things *seemingly* working, to the appearance of [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Comment: @lakesh First problem taken cared of, now it's just the second problem.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really work: calling a method from a null pointer is undefined behavior. The compiler can decide whether to crash the program, have it work anyway if the method doesn't use data members (which is what happens in your case), erase all data in your disk or even call SWAT teams at your place. You are lucky nothing bad happens in your case.

Comment: @lakesh same stuff applies, I didn't realize the code was wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done in undefined behaviour but you want to know why it works anyway in your case.

The reason is that the function `yellowdog::bark()` does not use the `this` in any way, plus the fact it is inlined into the header means the compiler may well have simply inlined its implementation for you.

In other words, it sees you called `bark()` on a `yellowdog` pointer and knows how to implement that, it substitutes the call with `cout << "woof." << endl`